# ESP8266-Arduino-Lua libraries and executing script from serial

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

For some reasons that I won't explain here, I'm programming a NodeMCU board with Arduino IDE. In order to send scripts instantaneously, I'm testing the ESP8266-Arduino-Lua libraries, which should complain with my needs by sending commands from the textbox in the serial monitor. In the example files, the executingscriptfromserial.ino, which I'm trying to run, may do the elementary command I need. The code compiles good and also the flash onto the board goes well. All the expected outputs comes out in the serial monitor: "Enter the lua script and press Control-D when finished:", I type my script but when pressing CTRL+D nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to proceed in this case?
ATM I'm not posting any codes, since it's not my work and I don't know the policies about. Anyway, I've provided you all the details for googling it and finding the files easily. If I can update the code, tell me and I'll edit this post.

Best regards and thanks all those will answer!

### Hardware config:

-OS: Windows 10 x64

-IDE: Arduino IDE 1.8.19

-Board: Wemos lol1n new NodeMCU v3